# How to deserialize a list as a single objects instead of a list object?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, yaml

I have the following Address and AddressList classes

```
public class Address {
  private String street;
  private String city;
  private String state;
  // ...
}


public class AddressList {
  private List<Address> addresses;
  // ...
}
```

and then a Person class

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = ListDeserializer.class)
  private Map<String, AddressList> addresses;
  // ..
}
```

Then I have the Yaml file like this

```
---
name: 'abc'
addresses:
  offices:
    - street: 123 main st
      city: san francisco
      state: ca
    - street: 234 post st
      city: san francisco
      state: ca
```

My List deserializer class is as follows:

```
public class ListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<AddressList> {


@Override
public AddressList deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return jsonParser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Address>>>() {
    });
}
```

}
my parsing code is as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
return objectMapper.readValue(inputYamlFile, Person.class);
```

when I read the list of addresses: it prints as

```
{offices=null}
```

Can anyone help with resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this issue using deserializing addresses map using Converter.

The modifications I made are

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  @JsonDeserialize(converter = AddressListConverter.class)
  private Map<String, AddressList> addresses;
  // ..
 }
```

I, then, wrote a new converter class for the AddressList.

```
public class AddressListConverter implements Converter<Map<String, List<LinkedHashMap>>, Map<String, AddressList>> {
@Override
  public Map<String, AddressList> convert(Map<String, List<LinkedHashMap>> stringListMap) {
      Map<String, AddressList> addressListMap = new HashMap<>();
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      for (Map.Entry<String, List<LinkedHashMap>> entry : stringListMap.entrySet()) {
         AddressList addressList = new AddressList();
         for(LinkedHashMap map: entry.getValue()) {   
          Address address = mapper.convert(map, Address.class);
          addressList.getAddresses().add(address);
         }
          addressListMap.put(entry.getKey(), addressList);
      }
     return addressListMap;
  }

  @Override
  public JavaType getInputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
    return typeFactory.constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, List.class);
  }

  @Override
  public JavaType getOutputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
      return typeFactory.constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, AddressList.class);
  }
}
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If it was serialized as a list you have to deserialize it the same way. But you then have the list and and can iterate it yourself.